# Updating Based on List

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need to inactivate a bunch of users. I have a list like this (sample):

N0120454
N0219746
N0074342
N0203867
N0155928
N0025471
N0017467
N0239158
N0191759
N0007671

```
UPDATE dbo.Users 
set IsActive = 0, IsLocked = 1
where UserName = 'N0007671'
```

Is there a way to perform this without doing it UserId by UserId?

Comment: Is the list of users to deactivate outside the system of so IN operator is reasonable provided it doesn't exceed a character max limit threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a hard-coded list the easiest way is to do:

```
UPDATE dbo.Users 
set IsActive = 0, IsLocked = 1
where UserName IN ('N0120454', 'N0219746', 'N0074342', 
                   'N0203867', 'N0155928', 'N0025471', 
                   'N0017467', 'N0239158', 'N0191759', 'N0007671')
```

If you expect to pass in a single string value containing a bunch of then it is simpler to loop through the values in the app.  Otherwise you'll need to use dynamic SQL, or write a function that parses the string into multiple values and uses a temp table to join to.  Neither are standard or pretty.

Answer (score 2):

May be using [in operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

```
UPDATE dbo.Users 
set IsActive = 0, IsLocked = 1
where UserName in( 'N0007671', 'N0219746', 'N0074342' ...)
```

If your vales are in the database table, you have 2 ways to do it

1 - Using [IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

```
UPDATE dbo.Users 
SET IsActive = 0, IsLocked = 1
WHERE UserName IN ( SELECT username 
                    FROM your_table 
                    WHERE conditions )
```

2- Using [EXISTS](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_exists.php)

```
 UPDATE dbo.Users 
 SET IsActive = 0, IsLocked = 1
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
                FROM your_table yt 
                WHERE yt.username = dbo.Users and others_conditions )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

```
where UserName in ('N0007671', 'N0219746' ... )
```